# Scaling an embedded <image> inside <svg> in IE 11+

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Before I give up and build my solution completely in SVG, I thought I would throw this out to the StackOverflow crowd to see if I missed anything.

In a current project, I have a .png that represents the faceplate of a real-world water irrigation controller.  The SVG acts an overlay and contains the coordinates of all the pressable buttons and virtual LEDs that blink when necessary on the real world device, interacting with a Node application that is talking to the 'real' water controller, and the .png is an embedded background image.  (see code below)  We programmatically (via Javascript) change the overlay SVG and the faceplate image on entry into the page, depending on earlier user input.

Everything works great, we can press buttons on the SVG overlay and the real world controller responds, and vice-versa.

The problem comes down to scaling the embedded image.  Under Chrome, Firefox, and Opera, I can resize the browser window to various sizes and the SVG and embedded image scale beautifully.[image: works great!]

But IE 11+ refuses to play ball, and stubbornly keeps the embedded image at a reduced size.[image: IE not playing nice]

I think I've googled-to-death everything on the subject of scaling SVGs in IE, and tried various CSS hacks and DOM manipulations, although *most seem to apply to embedding the SVG in an HTML img tag, and not an SVG with an embedded image tag*.

I've tried removing all width/height from the SVG and use CSS-only; I've tried using 100% width/height in the image tag to (supposedly) allow the viewBox to control it's dimensions; I've tried fixing the width/height to same values of viewBox; I've tried using preseveAspectRatio in both the SVG header and the image.  I'm running out of ideas.

Relevant code sample:

```
<svg class="scaling-svg" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 970 530" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" >

  <image id="faceplate" xlink:href="../images/TWC-front.jpg" class="svg-content" height="530" width="970" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"></image>

  <g>
    <rect id="rect_textDisplay" x="322" y="157" width="530" height="52" opacity="0" />
    <text fill="black" x="326" y="176" id="displine1" xml:space="preserve">Welcome to the Virtual Controller</text>
    <text fill="black" x="326" y="198" id="displine2" xml:space="preserve">  ...  waiting for connection</text>
  </g>

  <rect id="dial_irroff" x="39" y="319" opacity="0" width="75" height="25" />
  <rect id="dial_manual" x="63" y="287" opacity="0" width="80" height="25" />
  <rect id="dial_auto" x="148" y="278" opacity="0"  width="50" height="25" />
...
```

Any ideas or prodding in a direction I might not have considered are greatly appreciated.  I would like to keep the solution in the current form as much as possible, because we dynamically change the faceplate depending on user input, and there are about 15 different faceplates to be used between two SVG overlays.  It would take quite a bit more time to re-build each faceplate in pure SVG.  But I am prepared to do it, if necessary.  :(

Comment: Drop IE support and make them use Edge. Problem solved.

Comment: Try giving the image an explicit width/height i.e. width="100%" height="100%" on the root svg element.

Comment: Apply 100% height to html, body and svg element. If it still doesn't work use a 100vh height with modern browsers and a fixed height with IE.

Comment: @RobertLongson I mentioned that in my question "... I've tried using 100% width/height in the image tag to (supposedly) allow the viewBox to control it's dimensions..." ... or wait, you mean on the svg tag too?

Comment: @Mardoxx I was under the impression that Edge will not run on Win 7, 8.1, or Windows Phones - and these (among others) are the expected target groups in the US for this application, since it is possible that many have not upgraded to Win 10.  Besides, if I remember correctly, during testing a colleague pointed out it behaves just as badly on Edge.  :(

Comment: @llobet I'll try the 100% on all three, thanks.  As shown in the code snippet above, fixed height doesn't do diddly-squat in IE.

Comment: @thedigitalmouse Ahh man, can you put together a really simple reproduction on codepen.io and I shall challenge my webdev expert colleague to solve it tomorrow!

Comment: @Mardoxx will take a crack at that in the morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User llobet's comment above of adding 100% height to the html, body and svg elements seemed to do the trick.   Initially I took what worked in the codepen that user Mardoxx asked for and applied it to my CSS and it still did not work.  After a few minutes of pruning out all but the most basic of CSS rules *and* discovered a couple of `height: auto;`, attributes and removed them or made them 100%, then IE11 started playing nice and scaling as expected.  It pays to weed out and scruntinize your CSS until things behave as expected.  Thanks to both of you for pushing in the right direction.

Relevant codepen.io: http://codepen.io/digitalmouse/pen/LygOWe